# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, even after modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

Tags: environment-variables, julia, mpi, petsc

I have been trying to use `PETSc` for some `MPI` enhanced matrix operations, but I keep getting this error when I submit the job using `slurm` on a supercomputer:

```
ERROR: ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: could not load library 
"/home/20ph92r03/petsc/arch-linux-c-debug/lib/libpetsc.so"
liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directorycould not 
load library "/home/20ph92r03/petsc/arch-linux-c-debug/lib/libpetsc.so"
liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And this is my `jobscript`

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J slepcTest
#SBATCH -p standard-low
#SBATCH --output=slepcTest-out
#SBATCH -n 2
#SBATCH -t 1:00:00

module load compiler/intel-mpi/mpi-2020-v4

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/21ph92r03/julia-1.8.0/lib/julia:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

time mpiexec -n 2 /home/20ph92r03/julia-1.8.0/bin/julia mpiSlepc.jl
```

I have followed the earlier threads related to the same error and modified the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in the `.bashrc` file, like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'/home/20ph92r03/petsc/arch-linux-c- 
debug/lib/:/usr/lib64/'
```

But the error persists. I don't know what else to try!

Thanks!

Comment: If you expect /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3, make sure it is installed on the compute nodes.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet how do I know that?

Comment: run `ldd /home/20ph92r03/petsc/arch-linux-c-debug/lib/libpetsc.so | grep lapack` on your head node to confirm the location of the lapack library, then run `ls -l /xxx/liblapack.so.3` in your script to check the availability on the compute nodes.

Comment: I ran the above commands, the first one gives me: `liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3 (0x00002b54d7de5000)`. And then I submit my job script with `ls -l /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3` to get `ls: cannot access /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3: No such file or directory`. I guess then it's not installed on the compute nodes. So the next question is how to make sure it's installed on the compute nodes? Thanks!

Comment: Another thing I would like to add (if it's important) is that I get errors only while running the code on the cluster through job submission. It works fine if I run it on my head node.

Comment: It is clearly **not** installed on the compute nodes. The right fix is to ask your sysadmin to install it. Meanwhile, you can copy this library (and its dependencies such as `libblas.so.?`) in a shared directory and have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` point to it.

Comment: I would hope no sane sysadmin would install OS level lapack, but use actually well optimized, custom built, more modern BLAS packages, via the module system.